# EXCEL VBA Function with SELECT CASE, ELSE

Tags: database, validation, vba, excel

I have the my code for my function: The output of my funcion in j is the position of a column. Inside the function, "i" looks for the positions of rows which matchs with the variable "tutor" and "mes", then it gives the value of the cell(i,j).

The values of the cell(i.j) come frome a list of a sheet of excel. The values of the list are : "No cumple","Regular","Pleno","No se considera". Internally the function assings 0 for "No cumple", 1" for "Regular", 3 for "Pleno", and 0 for "No se considera".

The functions intends to calculate a mean for the values of each input ("tutor","mes","j") of the function.

When the case "No se considera" is in a cell, it means the if , for example, there are 5 values which the have to calculare the mean, "no se considera" is not taken into account, so the function just have to calculate the mean of 4 values.

The problem is that the function doesn't work when the value of cell(i.j) is "No se considera".

The code is the following:

```
 Public Function mespt(tutor As String, mes As String, j As Long)
Application.Volatile

Dim a As Long
Dim totalmesp As Double


mespt = 0
contador = 0
totalmespt = 0
For i = 4 To 1000
If Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = tutor And Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 = mes Then
Select Case Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, j).Value



Case "No cumple"
a = 0
Case "Regular"
a = 1
Case "Pleno"
a = 3
Case Else
contador = contador - 1
a = 0
End Select


totalmespt = totalmespt + a
contador = contador + 1
mespt = totalmespt / contador
End If
Next


End Function
```

Comment: You have `contador = contador - 1` followed by `contador = contador + 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Public Function mespt(tutor As String, mes As String, j As Long)
Application.Volatile

Dim a As Long
Dim totalmesp As Double


mespt = 0
contador = 0
totalmespt = 0
For i = 4 To 1000
If Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = tutor And Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 = mes Then
Select Case Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, j).Value



Case "No cumple"
contador = contador + 1
a = 0
Case "Regular"
contador = contador + 1
a = 1
Case "Pleno"
contador = contador + 1
a = 3
Case Else
contador = contador - 1
a = 0
End Select


totalmespt = totalmespt + a
mespt = totalmespt / contador
End If
Next


End Function
```

This is just a guess, but I'm *PRETTY* sure it's what you are looking for.

Comment: For example, What is expected is that If there's a value of "No se considera" and before I've calculate the mean of 4 values, then "No se considera" is not taken into account and the mean is the same because the sum of values is the same and the number of considered values is the same. And the problem is that the function doesn't calculate the correct mean when the position j gives "No se considera".

Comment: I think there´s a missunderstadning. In order to be more precise, I´ll give the following example:We have mespt("Jean","June",6) and there are three cells which match the conditions and have the values "Pleno","Cumple","No se considera". According to the algorithm, the funnction should assing the value 3 for "Pleno", 1 for "Cumple, and 0 for "No se considera". And mespt just calculates the mean of "Pleno" and "Cumple", "No se considera" is not taken into account to calculare it, so the mean is (3+0)/2 and mespt=2. Once more, the problem is when the value it`s a cell with "No se considera".

Comment: For the avobe-mentioned case, the desired output in mespt("Jean","June",6) is 2. But in the excel, it returns #Valor

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function mespt(ByVal tutor As String, ByVal mes As String, ByVal j As Long) As Double

    Dim totalmespt As Double
    Dim contador As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("Hoja1")
        For i = 4 To 1000
            If .Cells(i, "B").Value & .Cells(i, "E").Value = tutor & mes _
            And InStr(1, "|no cumple|regular|pleno|", "|" & .Cells(i, j).Value & "|", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                contador = contador + 1
                totalmespt = totalmespt + WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, j).Value, Array("no cumple", "regular", "", "pleno"), 0) - 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If contador > 0 Then mespt = totalmespt / contador Else mespt = 0

End Function
```